# If else statement that disables a button

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to make an `if else` statement that should disable a button from being pressed when the value of `c` is 1, but I can't seem to get it to work with `d3.js`.

HTML

```
<button type="button" id="bt1" class="bt1">Previous 10</button>
<button type="button" id="bt2" class="bt2">Next 10</button>
```

JS

```
d3.select("#bt2").on("click", () => {
    a += 10;
    b += 10;
    c += 1;

    update(a,b,c);
});

d3.select("#bt1").on("click", () => {
    a -= 10;
    b -= 10;
    c -= 1;
    update(a,b,c);
});

if (c = 1) { d3.select("bt1").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only using one `=`. This results in the `c` variable having its value affected to `1`, it does not test its value.

You can either use 2 or 3 `=`. See the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons).

```
if (c === 1) { d3.select("bt1").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); }
```